# Riesz representation theorem for $L^p$ spaces (References)

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm just looking for references about Riesz representation theorem for $L^p$ spaces and consequences.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* has a detailed discussion for it and there is a detailed 10 step proof provided as well (see pp. 40-47). He then defines the Lebesgue measure based on the Riesz Representation Theorem.

For the $L^p$ formulation you can have a look at Royden & Fitzpatrick's *Real Analysis*, 4e (e.g. pp. 160-161).